# Understanding how Python builtins are mapped to underlying C implementation

Tags: python

If I go to the implementation of let's say the `next()` builtin function, I'm forwarded to the `builtins.py` module to following code:

```
def next(iterator, default=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    next(iterator[, default])
    
    Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
    is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.
    """
    pass
```

Now, it looks like this functions does *nothing* but obviously that's not the case.

I understand that this function is implemented in C under the hood, but how and when is this function(or other builtin functions) mapped to the underlying C implementation?

If you have an answer to this question, can you please also provide links that I can read in order to better unterstand this topic?

I'm not asking, where the code is, but how and when the function is mapped to that code

Thank you.

Comment: What you're looking at isn't actually part of Python. It's not like this stub is ever "mapped to" the "actual implementation" in C. There is only the actual implementation in C. This stub file is just used by your IDE to, well, stub the function signature for auto-completion etc.

Comment: Would still be interesting to know how next() is interpreted and linked to the C implementation..

Comment: You're basically asking how Python works…? How it finds any name, whether builtin or user defined? Seems a bit broad. What about the process do or don't you understand? Perhaps we can fill in some gaps for you, if you tell us more about what gaps you have.

Comment: Do you know how next() is interpreted and linked to the C implementation or not?